# how to join with removing hyphens to match other table

Tags: sql

The table A has NDC (varchar(13) is in this format: xxxxx-xxxx-xx, table B NDC11 (char(11) is this format xxxxxxxxxxx but are the same numbers.

How can I get them to match up to complete the join on the two? I'm not sure how to drop the hyphens

```
left join REFERENCE.dbo.edw_drug as b
on a.ndc = b.ndc11
where a.report_nbr = '151'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: 
on replace(a.ndc, '-','')  = b.ndc11